# Gradle error 'Unable to resolve dependency' SDK Amadeus on Android Studio

Tags: android, kotlin, amadeus

I’m currently trying to use the Kotlin SDK of Amadeus API (https://github.com/amadeus4dev/amadeus-android).

I’m using Android Studio so I need to add `implementation "com.amadeus:amadeus-android:0.0.2"` in the Gradle.

But then the sync fails because of Amadeus.

Here are the errors displayed :

```
ERROR: Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debugAndroidTest/compileClasspath': Could not find Amadeus Android:trip:unspecified
ERROR: Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debugUnitTest/compileClasspath': Could not find Amadeus Android:trip:unspecified
ERROR: Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debug/compileClasspath': Could not find Amadeus Android:trip:unspecified

ERROR: Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debugAndroidTest/compileClasspath': Could not find Amadeus Android:air:unspecified
ERROR: Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debugUnitTest/compileClasspath': Could not find Amadeus Android:air:unspecified
ERROR: Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debug/compileClasspath': Could not find Amadeus Android:air:unspecified

ERROR: Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debugAndroidTest/compileClasspath': Could not find Amadeus Android:base:unspecified
ERROR: Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debugUnitTest/compileClasspath': Could not find Amadeus Android:base:unspecified
ERROR: Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debug/compileClasspath': Could not find Amadeus Android:base:unspecified

ERROR: Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debugAndroidTest/compileClasspath': Could not find Amadeus Android:hotel:unspecified
ERROR: Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debugUnitTest/compileClasspath': Could not find Amadeus Android:hotel:unspecified
ERROR: Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debug/compileClasspath': Could not find Amadeus Android:hotel:unspecified
```

Gradle, Android Studio and Kotlin versions are all up to date.
I tried with a new project but I still have the same errors.

Is there any way to solve this problem ? Or does it come from the SDK itself ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are right, the version 0.0.2 had an issue. It has been fixed and redeployed (on JCentral and MavenCentral). You can now use the amadeus-android version 0.0.4.

`implementation 'com.amadeus:amadeus-android:0.0.4'`

Note that the [Android SDK](https://github.com/amadeus4dev/amadeus-android) is still in beta version.

Comment: Thanks for fixing it ! I was thinking of using the Java SDK while the Android SDK is still in beta. But I'm a beginner in the field, so I was wondering if it could be problematic to use a Java SDK in a Kotlin environment?

Comment: You can do it, but you will have to manage the asynchronous calls manually. You will lose as well some functionalities of Kotlin doing this, this is one of the main reasons why we have decided to re-implement completely the SDK for Android. We are improving a lot the Android SDK and are very reactive to any issue you might face, hopefully, we will publish the first stable version soon. Meanwhile, let us know if you face any other issues!

Comment: So I tried to use Kotlin SDK. I wanted Flight Offers Search data but it doesn't seem to send the correct data. The json format I get with amadeus.shopping.flightOffersSearch isn't the same that the one I see when I use Postman or Java SDK. For example in data I have type, id, choiceProbability and offerItems which are not the parameters I should have according to Postman (and by the way choiceProbability and offerItems are always null). Maybe I use it wrong but I think there is a problem.

Comment: Thanks a lot for raising this! We had an issue with the way the object was returned. I just deployed a 0.0.4 that should fix the issue. We are working as on refactoring to simplify the way objects are handled (that will be totally transparent for the users but shouldfix somes issues). For `choiceProbability` it is because this value comes from another API (Flight Choice Prediction), this API takes the response of Flight Offers Search and apply our Machine Learning model on it to predict for each of the flight offers what is the chance that a trveler select that offer over the other ones.

Comment: Thanks for your reactivity ! But did you release the new version yet ? Version 0.0.4 fails to resolve and it seems that the last version available is still 0.0.3.

Comment: Hum weird, I see the release available on JCentral but not in MavenCentral, I requested an update to them meanwhile you should be able to get it from JCentral...

Comment: So I tried again. Now it finds the release but it can't resolve com.amadeus:hotel:0.0.4. Same for trip and base.

Comment: We have released a new version `0.0.5` that comes with quite a big re-factoring. We support now almost all the APIs, we support calls using amadeus.get("URL"). We have changed some models (some objects could have different names but we tried to keep the same as before), on the response models we do not treat the dates as Date but as String now, we improved the releasing (cleaner now and you shouldn't face any issue) we are getting closer to the first stable version! Thanks again for your feedback!